# Mollie : Not able to get response after payment is done

Tags: php, laravel, mollie

I am using **laravel** framework and trying to implement Mollie payment gateway. I have successfully implemented it.
But when I am trying to get a response after payment paid. **But i am unable to get the response even after success**

I am using code for retrieving payment response:

```
    $mollie = new \Mollie_API_Client();
    $mollie->setApiKey("test_mode_api_key");
    $payment = $mollie->payments->get($payment->id);
```

what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Abdulla Nilam its different environment. please check the question berfore marking.

Comment: `$payment->id` here how you get `$payment`??

Comment: Sohel its for retrieving id after payment done. I don't know much about it. thats why i have posted error  :(

Comment: please show what `$mollie->payments->get()` gives

Comment: please check the reference https://github.com/mollie/mollie-api-php

Comment: then how did you store??

Comment: actually don't know how its work :(

Comment: then how you expect others to do your task, consult with your colleague or read the documentation carefully first

Comment: Sohel, look I am filling the value into form , its redirect me into mollie payment gateway page, after payment done we can redirect to url and get response using defined code. But its giving me error.

Comment: you need to find how you are storing payment and get individual payment id recorded somewhere

Comment: payment id is auto generated when payment is done, but i am unable to retrieve it.

Comment: and i store it before payment, after payment i am just changing the status.

Comment: please add your save method

Comment: yes I will, if i get response from Mollie. :(

Comment: now,i am just printing it.

Comment: api doc is cleared, it is expecting an id, you need to provide it, so find a way

Comment: yes i need to find it on my end. Thanks for helping Sohel.

Comment: If anyone still looking for the solution, Actually Mollie's documentation is little misleading in description, Generally the return back url comes with a response from the gateway containing the necessary parameters but in this case you won't receive anything from the Mollie so the solution is save your `$id = $payment->id` before redirecting to the gateway and later on successful redirect, use the same `$id` in webhook to verify the status of payment.